# IF statement causing a segmentation error?

Tags: c++, if-statement, segmentation-fault

I have ran into a rather confusing problem. It seems like the IF statement in my program is causing me a segmentation error.

I am working with extern libraries, and calling the code from external libraries in the IF statement, so I can't provide the whole code of those functions because I don't have it either.

Basic example of what happens. So this example causes me a `Segmentation fault`.

```
IRank *rank;

//Generating wavelet tree from BWT with sdsl library
    if(true) {
        std::cout << "I am in IF" << endl; // this gets printed on the screen
        wt_huff<> wt;                      // right after that - segm fault
        construct_im(wt, BWT, 1);
        WTRank wtrank(&wt);
        rank = &wtrank;
    }
```

However, the same example, but without an IF, when I comment it out, does not cause `Segmentation fault`, and executes normally.

```
IRank *rank;

//Generating wavelet tree from BWT with sdsl library
//if(true) {
    std::cout << "I am in IF" << endl; // again this gets printed
    wt_huff<> wt;                      // no segmentation error this time
    construct_im(wt, BWT, 1);
    WTRank wtrank(&wt);
    rank = &wtrank;
//}
```

**Original example:**

```
//    // Decide what rank function to use
    IRank *rank;
    if(m_wt) {
        // Multiary Wavelet Tree rank function :: student implementation
        mwt::node *m_wtree = mwt::generateMultiaryWT(BWT, ary);
        MultiWTRank m_wt_rank(m_wtree, ary);
        rank = &m_wt_rank;
    } else if(b_wt) {
        // Binary Wavelet Tree rank function :: SDSL implementation
        wt_huff<> b_wtree;
        construct_im(b_wtree, BWT, 1);
        WTRank b_wt_rank(&b_wtree);
        rank = &b_wt_rank;
    } else if(non_wt) {
        // Implementation of rank function not using Wavelet Tree
        LinRank lin_rank(BWT);
        rank = &lin_rank;
    } else {
        // should not happen
    }

//...
run(rank);
```

What happens here, it is so confusing?

**EDIT: example of other code being called from this snipper**

```
    #include "IRank.h"
#include "mwt.h"


class MultiWTRank : public IRank {

private:
    mwt::node *wt;
    int n_ary;

public:
    MultiWTRank(mwt::node *root, int ary) {
        wt = root;
        n_ary = ary;
    }

    ~MultiWTRank() {
    }

    index_type rank(index_type index, symbol_type symbol);
};
```

So this is being constructed in the first IF.

**EDIT2: Providing a code that generates a pointer to the tree that could cause the trouble**

```
class mwt {
public:
    // Structure of a MW tree node
    typedef struct node {
        vector<int> data;
        vector<node*> next;
    } node;

    // ...



    static node* generateMultiaryWT(string input, int ary) {

        //...

        return root;
    }
```

Node is created like this:

```
   static node* InitRoot(int ary){
        node *root = new node;
        for(int iter = 0; iter < ary; iter++){
            root->next.push_back(NULL);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Declare the 'wt' and 'wtrank' variables before the if. If you declare it inside the block following the if, its scope is limited to that block. After the } it is out of scope and the 'rank' pointer becomes dangling, so accessing it later may cause a segfault.

Comment: Is there some workaround so it still can be in the if? Maybe using a reference?

Comment: The dangling pointer is to the `wtrank` object. The `wt` might also need to be outside the nested scope because its address is passed to the `WTRank` constructor. It's not exactly clear from just the given code.

Comment: @Whizzil: A reference won't help, they can dangle as well. You have a problem with your object lifetimes.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Right, the dangling pointer pointed at wtrank not wt. I edited my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost certainly some other code you have not shown doing something untoward - molesting a pointer, falling off the end of an array, accessing value of an uninitialised variable, etc.

Introducing an `if (true)` around some block, at most, will change memory layout of your program (e.g. if storage is set aside to hold the value `true`, and if the compiler emits some code to test it before executing the subsequent code).  Because the memory layout changes, the implications of misbehaving code (i.e. what gets clobbered) can change.

Naturally, in this case, the possible change depends on the compiler.  An aggressive optimisation may detect that `true` is always (well) `true`, and therefore eliminate the `if (true)` entirely from emitted code.   In this case, there will be no difference on program behaviour of having it or not.   However, not all compilers (or compiler settings) do that.

Incidentally, the advice to change where you define the variable `wt` might or might not work for similar reasons.   Moving the definition might simply change the order of actions in code (machine instructions, etc), or the layout of memory as used by your program (particularly if the constructor for that object allocates significant resources).   So it is not a solution, even if it might appear to work.   Because it is not guaranteed to work.  And may break because of other changes (of your code, compiler, compilation settings, etc) in future.

The thing is, the real problem might be in code you have shown (impact of functions being called, constructors being invoked, etc) or it might be in code executed previously in your program.   Such is the nature of undefined behaviour - when a problem occurs, the symptom may not become visible immediately, but may affect behaviour of unrelated code.

Given where the problem occurs, the `rank = &wtrank` statement is not the cause.   The cause will be in previous code.   However, that dangling pointer will be another problem for subsequently executed code - once this problem is fixed.

Comment: Let me post example of my "other" code, maybe you can tell me whats wrong. For sure if the problem is somewhere else, it in that what I am about to post.

Comment: The `if` blocks are absolutely a problem. Variables defined inside those blocks are destroyed when they go out of scope. The posted code is a good example of how to create a dangling pointer.

Comment: Well tell me how to achieve the wanted behaviour with no dangling pointers :D

Comment: @Whizzil: Variables with automatic storage duration ("on the stack") are destroyed when they go out of scope. One solution is to use dynamic allocation (`new` and `delete`). Of course then you have a resource management problem and the solution for that is __smart pointers__ like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @BlastFurnace - from information given, the fault (segmentation violation) is occurring within the `if` block - and before objects are passing out of scope.   What you're pointing out may be related to other problems - affecting subsequently executed code - but not the one asked asked about.

Comment: @Whizzil Well, when do you want `wtrank` to be destroyed?

Comment: @Peter: Does the segfault actually occur inside the block or is that an assumption because the last observed effect was the `cout`? Whizzil didn't say if it was pinpointed while inside a debugger. I don't know. I'd start fixing the obvious problem first.

Comment: @BlastFurnace - From the information given, there are potentially two problems in play - something causing statements within the `if()` block to fail [which will be caused by previous code, not shown] and subsequent problem due to dangling pointer/reference.   Both need to be checked - fixing one might eliminate symptoms, but still leave a future problem to emerge.   Basic fact of life:  buggy code can still appear to run correctly, so lack of symptoms is not evidence of correct code.

Comment: I tried changing ranks to work with NEW, but still sometimes I get segmentation faults..

Comment: @Whizzil: You might have larger design issues to resolve. For example, I see your `MultiWTRank` class copies a pointer passed to its constructor. Who owns __that__ object? Who manages its lifetime? I don't have a simple answer. Peter and jomuel's answers are helpful but you probably need to spend some time in your debugger or thinking through your design.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Well this is a pointer returned by a function mwt::generateMultiaryWTree(...). This function creates a tree, and returns a pointer to the root. It is a static function in a class. I can provide code.

Comment: @Whizzil: Who creates the `root` pointer in that function? Is it dynamically allocated or is it a local that will go out of scope? I also see that each `node` contains a `std::vector` of raw pointers to other nodes. Who creates/owns/deletes all of those? I'm sorry but it's late and I think I will leave this for others to help. Good luck.

Comment: It is dynamically allocated. I didnt write the rest of the code, I am just including it kind of, and using it.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you want the declaration of > wt in the IF statement?

Comment: Because I have multiple implementations of Rank function that can be used. Which one is being used is determined as the parameter to main function. I edited my post.